# Ошибки при изменении tasks.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Изначально у меня была создана конфигурация TypeScript Watch для сервера, но затем мне понадобилось разделить конфигурацию, создав их две и унаследовав от `tsconfig.json` в корне. Так вот в таске вотчера мне тоже нужно изменить путь к конфигурации. Захожу в `tasks.json` и меняю строчку на:

```
"tsconfig": "server/tsconfig.json",
```

И тут же выскакивает ошибка:

> Error: The typescript task detection didn't contribute a task for the following configuration:

Что значит эта ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

В графе "tsconfig" нужно указывать название конфигурационных файлов TypeScript, а не путь к какому-нибудь одному конкретному.